# how can i list every path in a directed graph? (C#)

Tags: c#, list, recursion, tree

please just point me in the right direction or tell me what to look up to solve this:

I have a "tree" object that holds "node" objects. (actually it's called a directed graph).
Each node holds the fields string "name" and "list" that contains the next nodes.

How can I create lists of all possible node names from the head node to the foot node?
each list is to hold a path from head to foot. the number of nodes from head to foot is always the same i.e: 6.

this is what the tree looks like:

[image]

that diagram should give me:

```
list 1: n1,n2,n4,n5,n7,n9,n13.
lsit 2: n1,n2,n4,n6,n8,n9,n13.
list 3: n1,n2,n4,n10,n11,n12,n13
```

and so on.

could some simply point me in the right direction? what kind of recursive algorithm should i use? should i use a recursive method or only loops? (i need to use this on the result of the dikstra algorithm.)

Comment: That's not really a tree, is it?

Comment: Assuming this is homework, please take a stab at a solution and we'll help you out.

Comment: Ideally you would use recursion for this but if you went node to node on that diagram you would end up repeating paths and going into an endless loop! you would have to perform some checking of node id's and exiting the recursion for that path if you wanted to only process a path once!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do either a BFS or a DFS, and keep track of the path along with the node. When the node has no more children, dump the path. Note that you have a graph/forest instead of a tree, but the algorithm I outlined will work just the same.

To start you off using a BFS:

```
Step 1. [n1]
Step 2. [n2(n1), n3(n1)]
Step 3. [n3(n1), n4(n1,n2)]
Step 4. [n4(n1, n2), n4(n1, n3)]
Step 5. [n4(n1, n3), n5(n1, n2, n4), n6(n1, n2, n4), n10(n1, n2, n4)]
Step 6. [n5(n1, n2, n4), n6(n1, n2, n4), n10(n1, n2, n4), n5(n1, n3, n4), n6(n1, n3, n4), n10(n1, n3, n4)]
```

...

and so on. In the end you will have your paths. which will get printed out. You can implement this algorithm without requiring recursion. Just loop till the array is empty.
Makes sense?

Comment: Thanx, the DFS is exactly what i needed. i am implementing my own version of it in c#, now. will post in a few days when complete so others can use it.

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works assuming your graph is acyclical, and there is exactly one "foot" node which has no out bound edges.  These seem like reasonable assumptions, but I'd state them explicitly before turning in the assignment if it were me.  Without both of these assumptions, the problem and solution are more complex.

Comment: Solution above works for multiple foot nodes and for various depths of the tree, as long as he prints and removes nodes when "list" on the nodes is empty. Will not terminate if the graph has a cycle.

Answer (score 2):

That's a graph, not a tree. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure

So... my pointer would be, you're looking for a solution in [graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)). If you get stuck, a bit of google-fu around that term and your problem should yield algorithms to implement.

Comment: In a directed graph, the edges point from somewhere to somewhere. Not the case in your graph. Your graph is a undirected graph.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the [iterator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern).  This should get you going in the right direction...

Comment: The iterator pattern would work neither on a graph, nor a directed graph, unless we have the constraint that each graph node can only point at one other, in which case we would have a singly linked list.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) helpful - it discusses the various kinds of tree traversal you can do. However, most likely what you want is a recursive descent, prefix traversal. Furthermore, the structure you describe is not a traditional tree - in that it has cross-shared nodes - it is probably a graph. There are some [graph traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)) algorithms as well. Just keep in mind, that if the graph has cycles, you will need to provide some kind of cycle detection to handle terminating the traversal.